# ReactJS randomly returns empty script rather than content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a weird issue using ReactJS, and [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router). I have my main `App` returning some basic HTML, which loads on the page fine:

```
App.routes = (
    <Router.Route name="app" path="/" handler={App.App}>
        <Router.DefaultRoute handler={App.Matches} />
    </Router.Route>
);

---

App.App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <App.NavBar />
                <div className="ui page grid">
                    <div className="four wide column">
                        One
                    </div>
                    <div className="eight wide column">
                        Two
                    </div>
                    <div className="four wide column">
                        Three
                    </div>
                </div>

                <Router.RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

The NavBar component loads fine, along with the HTML. However, I expect the Router to now load the default handler `App.Matches`:

```
App.Matches = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                Content
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

As far as I can see, this should work. However, when rendered, I just get an empty script tag below the ` div like so:

```
<script data-reactid=".0.2"></script>
```

Anyone know why? Really confusing me.

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle/etc. that demonstrates this? Is `App.Matches` assigned/created at the time the routes are defined?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue...